# Maven JAX-WS WSGEN "Class not found error"

Tags: java, maven, jax-ws, wsgen

When i try to Compile my program.  I get the following error message:

```
Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.2:wsgen (generate-wsdl) on project SimpleWebServices: Error executing: wsgen [-keep, -s, etc..........
```

So, I begin poking around and further up the error, I see this:

```
Class not found: "com.test.ws.services.SimpleServiceImpl"
```

It would appear that for some reason, the WSGEN cannot find my  value.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Here's my POM if interested...

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-wsdl</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsgen</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sei>com.test.ws.services.SimpleServiceImpl</sei>
                        <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

**User Edit:**
I think i got it (based on @Thomas suggestion).  It appears that I didn't specify the source folder in the POM Build area.  Resulting in my source not being compiled.

Adding:

```
<sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
```

Did the trick for me.

@Thomas if you post your answer, I'd be happy to give you answer credit.

Thanks for your reply,

Comment: Looks like a classpath issue, do you have the package that contains SimpleServiceImpl included?

Comment: You mean that `SimpleServiceImpl` is also generated (because `${project.basedir}` is `target/` dir)?

Comment: None of my code was being compiled(Which i didn't notice at first).  So within the POM, I specified the sourceDirectory.  This seemed then include my source in the compile and the rest was history....

Comment: curious enough that definition of `<sourceDirectory>` solved it, since the path `${project.basedir}/src/main/java` is the default path.

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
mvn clean compile jaxws:wsgen
```

instead of

```
mvn clean jaxws:wsgen
```

the problem is, that there is no compiled version available. `wsgen` will work for classpaths like JARs with ByteCode.

`sourceDirectory` `${project.basedir}/src/main/java` is maven default, so you doesn't have to set it necessarily.