# How can I find the WSDL file after a successful build?

Tags: java, maven, jax-ws

I'm developing a project containing different layers. I'm using Maven, JAX-WS, the Spring framework and Hibernate. I tried to generate the WSDL file using jax ws maven plugin. First I used a JRE 7 but it didn't work. When I used a JDK 1.7 this message appeared:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building BSCSwebservices Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [WARNING] The POM for bsh:bsh:jar:1.2b3 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.sun.xml.stream.buffer:streambuffer:jar:0.4 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The artifact woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.0 has been relocated to org.codehaus.woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.0
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ BSCSwebservices ---
[debug] execute contextualize
 [WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:compile (default-compile) @ BSCSwebservices ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @   BSCSwebservices ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\sayed\workspace\BSCSwebservices1\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ BSCSwebservices ---
 [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ BSCSwebservices ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\sayed\workspace\BSCSwebservices1\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
  T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) @ BSCSwebservices ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [BSCSwebservices] in [C:\Users\sayed\workspace\BSCSwebservices1\target\BSCSwebservices]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\sayed\workspace\BSCSwebservices1\src\main\webapp]
    [INFO] Webapp assembled in [607 msecs]
   [INFO] Building war: C:\Users\sayed\workspace\BSCSwebservices1\target\BSCSwebservices.war
   [WARNING] Warning: selected war files include a WEB-INF/web.xml which will be ignored 
  (webxml attribute is missing from war task, or ignoreWebxml attribute is specified as   'true')
    [INFO] 
   [INFO] --- jaxws-maven-plugin:1.11:wsgen (service_BillingAccountRead) @  BSCSwebservices ---
    [WARNING] The POM for woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.3 is missing, no dependency information available

warning: The apt tool and its associated API are planned to be
removed in the next major JDK release.  These features have been
superseded by javac and the standardized annotation processing API,
javax.annotation.processing and javax.lang.model.  Users are
recommended to migrate to the annotation processing features of
javac; see the javac man page for more information.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.635s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Aug 01 20:38:29 WAT 2013
 [INFO] Final Memory: 16M/38M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

this a part of pom.xml

```
 <plugins>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.11</version>
        <executions>  
                <execution>  
                    <id>service_BillingAccountRead</id>  
                    <phase>package</phase>  
                    <goals>  
                        <goal>wsgen</goal>  
                    </goals>  
                    <configuration>  
                        <sei>com.ws.BillingAccountRead</sei>   
                        <genwsdl>true</genwsdl>  
                        <keep>true</keep>  

                    </configuration>  
                </execution>   
            </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

The build succeeds, but I don't find the WSDL file? And is that the warnings that have an effect after I completed the other layer?

I added the dependency of all all jars appearing in warnings, but the warnings are still shown.

Comment: where are you looking for WSDL ?

Answer (score 0):

WSDL's get placed by default in {module_root}\target\generated-sources\wsdl

You REALLY need to start including relevant info in your questions. You haven't even posted the relevant parts of your pom. Have you even told jax-ws to generate a wsdl?

Also, fix the tonne of warnings getting spat out when you run your maven build. That just adds to the mess of info you are posting.

EDIT:

Go look up the documentation. You can explicitly state where the wsdls will end up. All of your questions have had simple answers which you could have found yourself with a minimal amount of effort on your part.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you build the project, the WSDL document file and the schema document files are not  generated automatically. This files are generated on deploy time by the application server. Internally, the server executes the [`wsgen`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsgen.html) tool to generate the files. Next, when you request the WSLD document file (add `?wsdl` on service endpoint) the application server *on the fly* update the service url in the files and serves.

If you want include the generation of this files, you can add in your `pom.xml` the [JAX-WS commons](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html). See an example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844938/maven-jax-ws-wsgen-class-not-found-error).